# How to read a text file if the file has multiple datas in a row those are separated using pipe(|) fs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to read a text file using node js fs module. 
My first question is , Does fs module support to read only text file or other file formats too ?

Now My main question is if the text file have the data like below, How do i read each data separately in the file ?..Please note some cell in the row could be empty as well.

```
James|Allister|12345|28|Sunderland|14

Andy|Cook|88888|33|New Jersey|16

Maria|Konsick|44||34
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fs` module doesn't understand file formats, it just reads buffers.  Optionally it can convert the buffers into strings.  As for that file, it's a csv just with `|` instead of `,`.

Parsing it is somethings like:

```
// split the lines into rows
const rows = raw.split('\n');
// split into columns
const data = rows.map(row => row.split('|'));
```

The empties will just be empty strings in the row arrays. You can filter them out. `rows.map(row => row.split('|').filter(el => el !== ''))` but most likely you'll want to leave them in for easy access my index.

But that assumes there are no escapes or other irregularities.  I recommend finding a csv module from npm.

Comment: The file i want to read is a text file , not a csv file. so in that case I believe fs module is more than enough.